# broadcom wifi in dell xps13 fails after update for the ∞th time

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, kernel, broadcom

Ubuntu 20.04
| Kernel: 5.8.0-48
| WIFI Adapter: BCM4352

I have had some version of this obnoxious wifi problem 15+ times over the last few years but this time I cannot seem to find a solution. Basically after an update or install ubuntu has some issues using my wifi driver in that it is totally unable to detect it.

Sometimes it has been really simple like a command or two, other times reinstalling a large portion of the kernel, but this time none of the past solutions are working for me and I have found myself stuck in a rough spot because I can usually use a USB wifi adapter to temporarily connect and get back online to fix the driver but after following [these official documentation instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#STA_-_No_Internet_access) my usb adapter does not even work... it does show both adapters on some level in the UI afterwards but they are not able to turn on or do anything, restarting does not help.

before it has shown the driver not in use and produced the error

```
pk-client-error-quark error while installing package bcmwl-kernel-source
```

which that is the most diagnostic I have ever gotten but this time I have no error at all and when I go to the additional drivers application or try to do the no-internet install from install media it appears the way it does when it is installed and working...

Comment: For most going back to the 5.4 kernel fixes this issue.

Comment: I tried kernel 5.8.0-44 which worked with the USB adapter only, and 5.4.0-70 which did not work with either adapter